# Como capturar o Header de uma requisição Curl PHP?

Tags: php, api, rest, libcurl

Estou montando uma API Rest local para teste e aprender o funcionamento de autenticação via Headers, dessa forma tenho 2 arquivos que vão interagir:

1: Client.php

```
$DadosArray = array();
$DadosArray["item"] = "1234";
$DadosArray["descricao"] = "Pedido teste";
$DadosArray["valor"] = "4321";

$buildQuery = json_encode($DadosArray);

$curl = curl_init("http://localhost/Server.php");
curl_setopt(
    $curl,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        "Authorization: 5a7753536b62545a6a684b",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    )
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $buildQuery);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$retorno = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

2: Server.php

```
$input_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

file_put_contents("Server.log", print_r($input_data , true));
```

Estou gravando em um arquivo de log o conteudo recebido no server e o resultado é

> `{"item": "1234","descricao":"Pedido teste","valor":"4321"}`

Até aí tudo bem consigo receber os dados, mas eu queria saber se consigo autenticar o TOKEN vindo de "Authorization" que está dentro do "CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER", pois ele não aparece nos dados json

Compreendo que o header não deva fazer parte do json, mas não faço ideia de como posso possível acessa-lo.

Procurei na web e encontrei bastante conteúdo para consumir APIs com Curl, mas nenhuma delas me mostrou como o lado do servidor trabalha na autenticação.

Eu poderia enviar o token no json Client, mas não acho que seja uma boa prática, eu queria fazer algo uma pouco melhor.

Gostaria se possível não utilizar componentes ou classes externas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as variáveis [`$_SERVER['HTTP_*']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) para obter as headers, no caso:

```
$input_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$authorization = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
```

Você também pode usar a função [`getallheaders()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders) (é um apelido para função [`apache_request_headers()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php))

Deve ficar algo como:

```
$headers = getallheaders();

var_dump($headers['Authorization']);
```

Em alguns casos, exemplo apache, é necessário configurar no .htaccess algo como:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Guilherme, consegui fazer usando o '$headers = getallheaders();' 10 pra você! Só comentando, não sei porque deram nota negativa porque expliquei no texto que não encontrei ou não compreendi solução nas pesquisas que fiz, mas cada uma cada um... só acho que esse votos negativos acabam tirando a credibilidade da solução encontrada no caso a sua. o assunto foi de fato resolvido e serve para futuras pesquisas.

Comment: Vale comentar que essa sugestão não funcionou pra mim: `RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

Comment: @Marcelo esta usando Apache e tem um `.htaccess`? Dizer não funciona pra mim não ajuda em nada a ajuda-lo. Tem que explicar. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: hum... você citou o .htaccess na resposta então imaginei que colocando só isso já daria pra deduzir que utilizo .htaccess, lendo na web vi que a opção poderia ser "RewriteRule . - [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]" sem o "e=", mas procurei por curiosidade já que a função "getallheaders" funcionou. Depois com mais calma tento de novo o .htaccess

Comment: @Marcelo pode ter sido que eu escrevi errado, não me lembro se as flags no rewriterule são case-sensitive ou insensitive, pode usar `[E]` ou `[env]`, só não sei se `[e]` minusculo funciona, como escrevi a regra na pressa acabei digitando assim, quando deveria ser [E], mas também pode ser erro no seu htaccess atual. Depois lhe confirmo.